# Passing a varible into a function to extract data from dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql

In below function i am passing my 'var selected = "this.calorieen"' into the table.find within the each function. However, this is a dataset. But I need the selected value to be a variable.

What happens now, is that it shows up as "this.calorieen" instead of as the datavalue "calorieen".

How can I fix this?

Function

```
loadIngredients("this.calorieen");
    function loadIngredients(selected) {    
        var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
        var datum = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
        var url = "restservices/loadingredients?Q1=" + username + "&Q2=" + datum;
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                method : "GET",
                beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                    var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                },
                success : function(data) {
                     $(data).each(function (index) {
                         $(".table").find('tr:last').prev().after('<tr><td class="ingredient">'+this.ingredientnaam+'</td><td class="hoeveelheid"><input class="gramtxt" type="text" value="'+this.hoeveelheid+'" name="gramtxt" id="gramtxt"></td><td class="subtotaal">"'+selected+'"</td><td class="removeingredient"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-times text-red"></i></a></td></tr>');
                        });
                     loadTotals();
                },
            });
    }
```

Comment: `loadIngredients("calorieen");` and in the each `this[selected]` is that what you mean?
ps sticking to one language makes your code more readable :)

Comment: @GertKommer Yes, that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".table").find('tr:last').prev().after('<tr><td class="ingredient">'+this.ingredientnaam+'</td><td class="hoeveelheid"><input class="gramtxt" type="text" value="'+this.hoeveelheid+'" name="gramtxt" id="gramtxt"></td><td class="subtotaal">"'+selected+'"</td><td class="removeingredient"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-times text-red"></i></a></td></tr>');
```

you should use `eval()` and pass upper code with some quote modifications into this function as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

loadIngredients("calorieen"); and in the each this[selected].  Thanks to GertKommer.